# Create a Table using JSON data from an API using Pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I am currently using Jquery to populate a table with data from an API, but I want to do it without requiring any external libraries, is there a way to do this using pure javascript?

I currently use the following solution:

```
$.ajax({
url: 'http://localhost:2672/api/notes',
type: 'GET',
success: function (myNotes) {
    console.log(myNotes)
    // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER. 
    var col = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myNotes.length; i++) {
        for (var key in myNotes[i]) {
            if (col.indexOf(key) === -1 && (key === 'title' || key === 'content' || key == 'category')) {
                col.push(key);
            }
        }
    }

    // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
    var table = document.createElement("table");

    // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

    var tr = table.insertRow(-1); // TABLE ROW.

    for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
        var th = document.createElement("th"); // TABLE HEADER.
        th.innerHTML = col[i];
        tr.appendChild(th);
    }

    // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
    for (var i = 0; i < myNotes.length; i++) {

        tr = table.insertRow(-1);

        for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
            var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
            tabCell.innerHTML = myNotes[i][col[j]];
        }
    }

    // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
    var divContainer = document.getElementById("showNotes");
    divContainer.innerHTML = "";
    divContainer.appendChild(table);
}
});
```

Comment: This is quite broad. You'd benefit from constraining it more and posting what you've tried already.

Comment: Please add your current jQuery code to the question.

Comment: I've looked around a bit, but all the examples I have found required Jquery, I'll post my current solution.

Comment: Yes @Frink, then we can help fix your problem.

Comment: So you really just need to convert the ajax-based data retrieval into "plain" javascript? Just curious, why not use jquery? It's certainly easier than rolling your own.

Comment: I'm using express.js, and it only loads the jquery js once, and it won't load it again, so it always just returns null when I try to retrieve it, so I need something that doesn't reply on a dependency. The current code I am using can be found at https://github.com/note-farm/frontend, under the express.js branch

Comment: @Frink please, check / comment / vote on answers :) it helps us to know if it was helpful

Comment: Sorry @AlexPakka, I dont have a very good reputation, so my votes aren't public yet. I did mark one as the best answer. Sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we do it the modern way, it is not that much code. This will work in Chrome / FF and any other modern browser. Note, that I fake-load JSON in [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) Promise's catch clause for demo purposes, you should obviously remove it in your code.

Once you grasp how you can use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to manipulate collections of data, it will simplify the code a lot.

The code below can be much shorter, but I wanted to provide some readability.

```js
const wrapper = document.getElementById('content');

const demoData = [
  {"id":1, "name":"John", "age":21},
  {"id":2, "name":"Bob", "age":19},
  {"id":3, "name":"Jessica", "age":20}
];

function fetchData() {
  fetch("data.json")
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(jsonData => populate(jsonData))
      .catch(e => {
          wrapper.innerText = "Error: "+e+" going to use demo data";
          populate(demoData); //remove me
      });
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fetchData, false);

function dom(tag, text) {
    let r = document.createElement(tag);
    if (text) r.innerText = text;
    return r;
};

function append(parent, child) { 
  parent.appendChild(child); 
  return parent; 
};

function populate(json) {
    if (json.length === 0) return;
    let keys = Object.keys(json[0]);
    let table = dom('table');
    //header
    append(table,
      keys.map(k => dom('th', k)).reduce(append, dom('tr'))
    );
    //values
    const makeRow = (acc, row) =>
        append(acc,
            keys.map(k => dom('td', row[k])).reduce(append, dom('tr'))
        );
    json.reduce(makeRow, table);
    wrapper.appendChild(table);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
success: function (myNotes) {
              var cols = Object.keys(myNotes[0]);
              var headerRow = '';
              var bodyRows = '';
              
              cols.map(function(col) {
                  headerRow += '<th scope="col">' + col + '</th>';
              });

              myNotes.map(function(row) {
                  bodyRows += '<tr>';
                  cols.map(function(colName) {
                      bodyRows += '<td>' + row[colName] + '<td>';
                  });
                  bodyRows += '</tr>';
              });
              return '<table class="table table-striped table-dark"' +'><thead><tr>' +headerRow +'</tr></thead><tbody>' +bodyRows +'</tbody></table>';
          }
```